# Do abstract characters in the translation character set differ from Unicode scalar values?

Tags: c++, unicode, language-lawyer, c++23

Consider the following sequence of bytes in hexadecimal representation (ASCII interpretations, if any, in the second column as a reading aide):

```
0x73 s
0x74 t
0x61 a
0x74 t
0x69 i
0x63 c
0x5f _
0x61 a
0x73 s
0x73 s
0x65 e
0x72 r
0x74 t
0x28 (
0x55 U
0x27 '
0xe2
0x84
0xab
0x27 '
0x3d =
0x3d =
0x55 U
0x27 '
0xc3
0x85
0x27 '
0x29 )
0x3b ;
```

Decoded as UTF-8 this byte sequence reads

```
static_assert(U'Å'==U'Å');
```

Note that on the left side `Å` is Unicode scalar value

```
0x212B ANGSTROM SIGN
```

and on the right-hand side `Å` is Unicode scalar value

```
0x00C5 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE
```

Is the assertion supposed to fail in C++23 when the byte sequence is interpreted as a source in the mandatorily-supported UTF-8 encoding?

---

In translation phase 1, after decoding the UTF-8 sequence to a Unicode scalar value sequence, these scalar values are supposed to be mapped to elements of the translation character set to form a sequence of translation character set elements, see [[lex.phases]/1.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.1.sentence-5). According to [[lex.charset]/1.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.charset#1.1) the elements of the translation character set are, with the exception of unassigned scalar values, the *abstract characters* which have an assigned Unicode code point.

The closest definition I could find for *abstract character* is in the Unicode standard. However, according to its chapter 3.4. D11 an *abstract character* can be assigned multiple code points and it gives the Angstrom character as an example. (EDIT: Carefully reading again, it doesn't say "*assigned*", just "*correspond to*".)

If this is the definition of *abstract character* meant in the C++ standard draft, isn't there then supposed to be only *one* element in the translation character set which is equivalent to the single abstract character represented by both the code points 0x212B and 0x00C5? If so, shouldn't then the value of both character literals be the same since the value is derived from the translation character set element which doesn't retain any information about the original scalar value?

This does not seem intended to me. Does Unicode even provide complete information on which code points refer to the same *abstract character*? But then, what exactly is meant by *abstract character* in the standard draft?

Comment: I know this is tagged `language-lawyer`, but did you try it?  I can't see the compiler being that clever, personally.

Comment: @PaulSanders GCC and Clang fail the assertion and for MSVC I don't know how to convince it to take the input correctly as UTF-8 (might be a compiler explorer issue or some missing flag). See https://godbolt.org/z/W9chK45WK. The mandatory support for UTF-8 is new in C++23 and the exact wording I am concerned about has only recently been added, so I don't expect compilers to have this implemented correctly already. Also, I doubt that my understanding of _abstract character_ is the intended one.

Comment: Required flag is `/utf-8`, and your `static_assert` fails: https://godbolt.org/z/Y3b8Phv7E

Comment: Those are *not* the same characters even if they're visually very similar.  Why would you expect them to compare equal?

Comment: What is the point of showing everyone the hex for `static_assert`? Surely the hex for anything but the two characters in question is irrelevant noise..?

Comment: @MarkRansom Because, according to the example in chapter 3.4 D11 of the Unicode core specification, the code points 0x00C5 and 0x212B correspond to the _same abstract character_, which I guess also means that they ought to _not_ be visually distinct.

Comment: @ildjarn The encoding of the source is relevant, because for non-UTF-8 encoded input the whole translation to translation character set elements is implementation-defined. I can't be sure that Stackoverflow or a user's browser won't mess with the string as  Unicode scalar value sequence and providing the exact byte values of the input guarantees that there is no misunderstanding. (Also, there are multiple well-formed UTF-8 sequences that decode to the Unicode scalar value sequence.)

Comment: Any chance of a link to "chapter 3.4. D11" of the Unicode Standard? Reading that *may* clarify what it means by assigning multiple code points. (E.g. the Angstrom symbol *could* be represented as a plain "A" plus a *combining* top-ring.)

Comment: But, in terms of the C++ Standard and characters that *look* the same, then what about those Greek capital letters that - in most fonts - are indistinguishable from Latin capitals (capital "alpha" looks the same as capital "a", for example).

Comment: @AdrianMole I don't know whether there is an easy way to link to a specific part of the Unicode specification, but the whole chapter in PDF form is [here](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/ch03.pdf). According to it an abstract character may also be representable by a sequence of more than one code point, which is the case when using combining marks as you suggest. However, the C++ standard speaks of abstract characters which have assigned code points (i.e. I guess _encoded characters_ in Unicode terminology), which doesn't seem to include such considerations.

Comment: Then I guess that's your misunderstanding. The `[lex.charset]` section of the C++ Standard that you link seems quite clear that each codepoint that is an abstract character is a *distinct* character.

Comment: @AdrianMole GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA and LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A I think are not supposed to be the same abstract characters, but just sharing the same glyph. Chapter 3.4. D7 says that these are distinct concepts and that abstract characters are not about the actual form taken. But if someone more knowledgable about Unicode could clear this up, I'd be happy.

Comment: @AdrianMole [lex.charset]/1.2 which says "_a distinct character for each Unicode scalar value not assigned to an abstract character._" applies only to Unicode scalar values that have no assigned abstract character (e.g. noncharacter code points or code points that are reserved for future assignment), but both 0x212B and 0x00C5 have an assigned abstract character. So [lex.charset]/1.1 applies and it says that the abstract character itself is the element of the character set, not one character for each code point.

Comment: Does p2736 help? It didn't clarify for me. Good question.

Comment: @JeffGarrett It doesn't help me really. Before P2736 the standard was referencing "characters" in the sense of ISO/IEC 10646 instead of "abstract character" in the sense of Unicode. It also claimed that each such character was identified by its _unique_ UCS scalar value. I haven't looked into ISO/IEC 10646 whether it also considers scalar values 0x212B and 0x00C5 to refer to the same character so that this wouldn't have made sense either or whether ISO 10646 differs from the Unicode standard in this aspect beyond the exact terms used. (Or whether I misunderstand something completely.)

Comment: Also, see https://lists.isocpp.org/sg16/ (Jan-Feb at least). I saw some messages debating abstract character suggesting they did know it in the Unicode sense.

Comment: Here is the meeting where it was discussed: https://github.com/sg16-unicode/sg16-meetings/#january-11th-2023

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is really about what "abstract character" really means. That's defined by the Unicode standard.

You cited that an abstract character may map to multiple code points. Or even codepoint sequences.

The problem is that the rest of the standard doesn't seem to agree.

If you look at the Unicode tables (also defined in the Unicode standard), there is no specification on "U+212B" or "U+00C5" that they code to the same abstract character. The [entry for U+212B](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2100.pdf) says:

> • preferred representation is 00C5 Å
> ≡ 00C5 Å latin capital letter a with ring above

However, [the ≡ symbol is defined to mean](https://www.unicode.org/charts/About.html#Conventions), "canonical decomposition mapping". And if you [head to the glossary to look that up](https://www.unicode.org/glossary/#canonical_decomposition), you'll find that this says *nothing* about what the abstract character is.

In fact, if you look around the glossary, you may stumble upon the definition of "[character name](https://www.unicode.org/glossary/#character_name)":

> Character Name. A unique string used to identify each abstract character encoded in the standard. (See definition D4 in Section 3.3, Semantics.)

So, every "abstract character" "encoded in the standard" has a "unique string" associated with it.

Therefore, if "U+212B" and "U+00C5" have different "character name" properties, they *must be* different abstract characters.

And if you [look them up in the Unicode Character Database](https://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html), they do in fact have different "character names". Ergo, they are different "abstract characters", which have different Unicode code-points and therefore do not compare equal.

This contradicts the example given in the quoted part of the Unicode standard. So the problem is that the Unicode standard *itself* is inconsistent. The database that defines the mapping is inconsistent with part of the text.

It may well be that this is the only place in the standard where it claims that multiple code points map to the same abstract character.

That being said, I would say that the C++ standard should use the term "encoded character" rather than "abstract character". The former clearly and unequivocally refers to a specific code point assigned to a character. Note that even the [*definition* of "encoded character"](https://www.unicode.org/glossary/#encoded_character) does not recognize the possibility of multiple code points mapping to an abstract character: "between an abstract character and a code point." Those are both *singular*.

Comment: This seems to make sense. After reading again carefully, the example I am referring to doesn't claim that multiple code points can be _assigned_ to the same abstract character. Just that they may _correspond_ or _represent_ the same abstract character (which I guess would mean after decomposition mapping). So it doesn't even seem to be an inconsistency, but a bit confusing.